# Modulo of difference of terms

Tags: c++, modulo

As an answer to a particular problem, I have to print `n*k^n - (n-1)*k`.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    c=(c%p*k%p)%p;
    c=(c%p*n%p)%p;
    d=((n-1)%p*k%p)%p;
    s=(c%p-d%p)%p;
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Initially `c=1`, `p=1000000007` and `s` is my final answer.
I have to take the modulo of s with respect to p.

For large values of `n`, `s` becomes negative. This happens because the modulo value changes. So even if `c>d`, it is possible that `c%p<d%p`. For `n=1000000000` and `k=25`, `s=-727999801`. I am not being able to think of a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-2 % 7 = 5`, because `-2 = 7 * (-1) + 5`, while c++ modulo operation would return `-2`, so to get positive number you just need to add `p`.

```
if (s < 0) s += p;
```

I advise you to rewrite your code in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c = (c * (k % p)) % p;
}
c = (c * (n % p)) % p;
int d = ((n - 1) % p * (k % p)) % p;
int s = (c - d) % p;
if (s < 0) s += p;
cout << s << endl;
```

To check with some small inputs you can use the following line:

```
cout << (n * (int)pow(k, n) - (n-1)*k) % p << endl;
```

Try to run with this input:

```
const int n = 5;
const int p = 7;
const int k = 10;
int c = 1;
```

You will see that without `if (s < 0) s += p;` it is `-1`. This line fixes it to `6` - the right answer.

Comment: I want the difference between `n*k^n - (n-1)*k` but c becomes less than d. How do I obtain the modulo of the original difference?

Comment: The logic is correct, but the website gives me a wrong answer. Must be a problem with the formula. Thank you for your help @Yola.